# Is this gradient an isomorphism on its range?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, sobolev-spaces, partial-derivative

Consider the gradient (in the weak sense) as an operator $\nabla \colon H^1(\Omega)/\mathbb{R} \to [L^2(\Omega)]^d$, where $\Omega \subset \mathbb R^d$ is a domain with a smooth boundary and $d\in\{2,3\}$ is the space dimension.

Here, $[L^2(\Omega)]^d$ denotes the space of tuples or triples of square integrable functions and $H^1(\Omega)$ is the space of $L^2(\Omega)$ functions with weak derivatives in $L^2(\Omega)$. Then $H^1(\Omega)/\mathbb R$ is made up by the equivalence classes of functions that differ only by a constant.

Is this $\nabla$ an homeomorphism on its range, i.e. is it injective and is its image closed in $[L^2(\Omega)]^d$?

**EDIT** thanks to @5pm for the hints

Comment: Well, I have a paper, where this fact is simply stated without proof. [ [preprint, the line after (3.10)](http://staff.science.uva.nl/~rstevens/papers/VarFormnse_27-12-11.pdf) ] So I thought this is a simple question for someone familiar with the subject. But I will have a closer look at it and then share my findings.

Comment: It's a bounded operator by definition of $H^1$. It also has a positive lower bound, known as the [Poincaré  inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9_inequality).

Comment: More direct argument: any linear operator with positive lower bound  has closed range. Because if $Tx_n\to y$, then $x_n$ converge too. // Please post answer as an answer, not as edit to question; just to keep each thing in its proper place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Summarizing the hints by @5pm, we can state:

Since the norm in $H^1(\Omega)/\mathbb{R}$ is equivalent to the $L^2$-norm of the gradient, one has that the $\nabla$ as defined above is bounded from below. Thus, $\nabla$ is injective and, as it is linear, also closed.